# Auto refresh script in command line

Tags: php, command-line

I'm using the command line to execute my php scripts instead of executing them in the browser, so I can look for errors a bit quicker. For browser there are some auto-refresh applications/plugins, so you don't have to hit CMD+R all the time.

For my error log I can use the `tail -f` command, but sure enough it doesn't execute/compile, so I can't use it for php files in the command-line.

Is there some equivalent or any work-around for compiled php-files ? Would be even greater to only output something in case of an error (native php-error like warnings, notices)!

Working on mac os/x if that's somehow helpful.

Comment: You can `tail -f` the error log (enable PHP to log all errors, warnings, notices into a file, tail & follow it). Otherwise work with a terminal/shell and just press the up arrow key and you'll have the last command you can then fire-up again. Probably ctrl+r works to search the history of commands as well under OSX.

Comment: tail -f the error log, should have thought about that! @hakre you're the best, period! Be great if you could enter this solution as an answer, guess thats the best recommendation for such scenarios!

Comment: Added an answer with some other thing which might be interesting for you. I use something like that on my linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `tail -f` the error log (enable PHP to log all errors, warnings, notices into a file, tail & follow it).

Also checkout notification scripts which will create a bubble if something happens, e.g. something like [How to get a pop up notification of a PHP error](http://mikeyp.net/archives/2008/06/how_get_a_pop_notification_a_php_error.html).

Otherwise work with a terminal/shell and just press the up arrow key and you'll have the last command you can then fire-up again. Probably ctrl+r works to search the history of commands as well under OSX.

Comment: Great hakre, can't emphasize how I love your solution because of simplicity. Control+R works, and Control+C terminates the `tail` in case someone else needs to know!

Answer (score 3):

The [watch](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/22/install-watch-command-on-os-x/) command does what you want.

> watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

You can do something like:

```
watch php myscript.php
```

and it would execute that command every two seconds and report it's output.

It even has flags to highlight differences from previous output.

Comment: tried that already as I saw it somewhere, but somehow my os x terminal returns `command not found` :(

Comment: Look at the link, it's not installed by default on OSX.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Going with hakre's solution though, just the best! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Combine with OSX command :-

```
while [ 1 ]
do
   php -r THE_FILE | grep -Ei "notice|warning|error"
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Wicked, just what I needed! Btw can you also explain how to stop the loop ?

Comment: ctrl + c will kill the loop. You can use the watch but you need to install into mac, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever